PyQGIS capture screen around mouse pointer
I'm developing a PyQGIS plugin, that shows different terrain details for the area hovered by the mouse pointer. I'd like to implement a screenshot feature that would allow the user to screenshot the area around the cursor on the Raster, and add the text containing these terrain details.
However I haven't been able to find a way to take screenshots like this, that would also include the cursor in the image, as well as the custom text of the terrain analysis. Are there any ideas on how I could implement this?

grabWindow perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60692523/737471
